# issue with with MKAnnotation image property

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am implementing a MKMapView based application. In that I am using a custom image instead of displaying a pin by using MKAnnotationView.Image property. It is not working. It keeps showing the standard pin in red but not the image I am pointing too. Any ideas?

```
- (void)setPin:(MKPinAnnotationView *)aPin forAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)anAnnotation {
    if (anAnnotation == self.userAnnotation) {

        aPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youarehere.png"];
        aPin.opaque = NO;

        aPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you are calling this from.  What does the viewForAnnotation method look like?

Comment: - (void)setCalloutForAnnotation:(Annotation *)annotation {
 MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
 pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = annotation.locationsCount > 1 ? self.calloutButton : nil;
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `MKPinAnnotationView` like you are then you don't get to set the image only the pinColor. `MKPinAnnotationView` only has `pinColor` and `animatesDrop` as the properties.

You want to use the parent class `MKAnnotationView`. It will let you set the image.

Read the Class Reference for each and it will make sense. This is one of the times that Objective-C makes me crazy because when you are reading those long class names in the docs, it's easy to scan right over the "Pin" variation in the class name.